# Find % difference between 4 running values

Tags: excel-formula

I'm looking to provide a formula to find the % difference per year between the first number (17846.86) and the last number (4850.72). This has ran for 4 years which equates to a change of 35.2239% per year. Can anybody help with a formula that would give this result in just 1 cell?

Just to highlight what the numbers would be via a formula:

2017 - 17846.86

2018 - 11560.50 - Change of 35.2239%

2019 - 7488.44 - Change of 35.2239%

2020 - 4850.72 - Change of 35.2239%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a formula:

((LastYearValue/FirstYearValue)^(1/CountYears))*100

Example:
(A5/A1)^(1/count(A1:A5)))*100

Comment: Thank you very much! this has been very helpful and taught me about power maths!

Comment: I’m happy that I could help!